# Package Frontespizio

Tags: templates, front-matter

I'm Italian. For my degree thesis I've found (and used) the package `frontespizio`.

Now I'm at the master thesis, in English, and I would like to know whether there exists a similar package in English. For example, I need to write "supervisor" instead of "relatore" and I think I can't change those parameters in the package `frontespizio`, though I would.

I've seen a lot of frontispiece templates but they're not too similar to the usual Italian thesis frontispiece.

Alternatively, how could I reproduce by myself the same output of such a package?

Comment: In the `frontespizio` environment add `\NRelatore{Supervisor}{Supervisors}`. You really need to read the [`frontespizio` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/frontespizio/frontespizio.pdf), it's in Italian, too.

Comment: As giordano says, you can customize every element of the frontispiece; not their relative positions, but I believe this is not your problem. “Ask and ye shall receive.” `;-)`

Comment: @giordano: Write a short answer from your comment and egreg’s addition.

Answer (score 5):

As [explained](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161179/package-frontespizio?noredirect=1#comment368770_161179) by egreg, the `frontespizio` package allows you to customize every element of the frontispiece, but not their relative positions.  You only need to read the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/frontespizio/frontespizio.pdf) (it's in Italian, only comments to the code are in English).

To answer your question, you can replace the word "Relatore" with "Supervisor" adding

```
\NRelatore{Supervisor}{Supervisors}
```

in the `frontespizio` environment.  The syntax of `\NRelatore` is

```
\NRelatore{<singular>}{<plural>}
```

Here is a full translated example taken from the documentation

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[nouppercase]{frontespizio}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontespizio}
  \Istituzione{University of St.\ Anford}
  \Divisione{Department of Typography}
  \Scuola{Ph.D. degree in \TeX{} and \LaTeX{}}
  \Titolo{How to prepare a\\
    formal frontispiece}
  \Sottotitolo{Theory and practice}
  \NCandidato{Candidate}
  \Candidato{Enrico Gregorio}
  \NRelatore{Thesis advisor}{}
  \Relatore{Prof. R. J. Drofnats}
  \NCorrelatore{Research supervisor}{Research supervisors}
  \Correlatore{J. H. Quick}
  \Correlatore{B. L. User}
  \Piede{Thesis submitted in 2010}
\end{frontespizio}
\end{document}
```

> [image: frontispiece example]

Comment: I'd surely get the degree, thanks to prof. Drofnats, of course.

Comment: Great answer! `:)` Just make sure @egreg submits the final version in Word. `:P`